# Syntax error in awk script

Tags: regex, bash, awk

I'm getting a syntax error when running an awk script, the script is:

```
awk -F\" 'for( i = 1 ; i <= NF; i++){if ($i == "^[0-9]+$"){ gsub(.,,,$1) }}'
```

A sample of how the actual data may look like is this (enclosed and pipe separated):

```
"data"|"data"|"data"|"data"|"data"
```

What i want to do, as you can see from the code is: read all fields, if a field is numeric (will always be decimal), replace the point with a comma.
I have also tried to escape the comma in the gsub function:

```
awk -F\" 'for( i = 1 ; i <= NF; i++){if ($i == "^[0-9]+$"){ gsub(.,\,,$1) }}'
```

But its not solving the issue, do you have any idea where the problem is? the comparison against a regex it looks fine, the loop and the if statements also, the error message is

```
    awk: cmd. line:1: for( i = 1 ; i <= NF; i++){if ($i == "^[0-9]+$"){ gsub(.,,,$1) }}
awk: cmd. line:1: ^ syntax error
awk: cmd. line:1: for( i = 1 ; i <= NF; i++){if ($i == "^[0-9]+$"){ gsub(.,,,$1) }}
awk: cmd. line:1:            ^ syntax error
awk: cmd. line:1: for( i = 1 ; i <= NF; i++){if ($i == "^[0-9]+$"){ gsub(.,,,$1) }}
awk: cmd. line:1:                     ^ syntax error
awk: cmd. line:1: for( i = 1 ; i <= NF; i++){if ($i == "^[0-9]+$"){ gsub(.,,,$1) }}
awk: cmd. line:1:                           ^ syntax error
awk: cmd. line:1: for( i = 1 ; i <= NF; i++){if ($i == "^[0-9]+$"){ gsub(.,,,$1) }}
awk: cmd. line:1:                                                 ^ syntax error
awk: cmd. line:1: for( i = 1 ; i <= NF; i++){if ($i == "^[0-9]+$"){ gsub(.,,,$1) }}
awk: cmd. line:1:                                                          ^ syntax error
awk: cmd. line:1: for( i = 1 ; i <= NF; i++){if ($i == "^[0-9]+$"){ gsub(.,,,$1) }}
awk: cmd. line:1:                                                           ^ syntax error
awk: cmd. line:1: for( i = 1 ; i <= NF; i++){if ($i == "^[0-9]+$"){ gsub(.,,,$1) }}
awk: cmd. line:1:                                                              ^ 1 is invalid as number of arguments for gsub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this line may work for you:

```
awk  'BEGIN{FS=OFS="\""}{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++)if($i~/[0-9\.]*/)gsub("\\.",",",$i)}1' file
```

test :

```
kent$  echo '"1000.18"|"4.8"|"data"|"data"|"3.5"'|awk  'BEGIN{FS=OFS="\""}{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++)if($i~/[0-9\.]*/)gsub("\\.",",",$i)}1'
"1000,18"|"4,8"|"data"|"data"|"3,5"
```

the problems in your code are:

- your for loop should be wrapped with `{}`
- you should use `~`, not `==` for regex matching
- even if you used ~, your regex is not correct. `^[0-9]+$`match only numbers, 20.8 is not matched. because there is a dot
- in gsub, the first parameter is regex you want to replace. if you simply put a dot in it. it means any character. you have to escape it, to let gsub know that you just want to replace the "dot".

Comment: Hi Kent, thx for the code snippet and the clear and helpful tips, there is something wrong with the regexp though, its matching also Strings, try this, it will format the (data.data) into (data,data): echo '"1000.18"|"4.8"|"data.data"|"data"|"3.5"'|awk  'BEGIN{FS=OFS="\""}{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++)if($i~/[0-9\.]*/)gsub("\\.",",",$i)}1'

Comment: if($i~/[0-9].[0-9]*/)  this has solved the thing, thx a lot Kent!

Comment: @JBoy yup, my regex is not strict enough. glad to help though.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing a Curly brace before for.
You can try like this

```
awk -F\" '{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++){if($i=="^[0-9]+$"){gsub(".",",",$1); }}}'
```